# alternative to FlexibleInterceptionModule in latest AutoFac

Tags: autofac

I'm trying to upgrade my project from AutoFac 1.4.4 to the latest version (2.4.5).  My code uses FlexibleInterceptionModule (to support proxy methods) which is no longer available in AutoFac.  Is there any other alternative for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 2.x you'll need to choose between 'class' and 'interface' interceptors. The [tests for the new DP integration](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/source/browse/contrib/Test/AutofacContrib.Tests.DynamicProxy2/) have some examples.

Hope this helps,

Nick